# Simple multiplication but compiler is taking more than a minute to produce the answer

Tags: c

My Code is taking too much time and possibly giving a wrong answer after a certain limit . What i have observed is the code slows down after I give N>50000 .

```
int solve(int N)
{
    long long int temp=0;
    long long int sum=0;
    const long long int mod=1000000007;

    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=N;j++)
        {
                temp=0;
                if((i&j)==0)
                {
                temp=i*j;
                sum=sum+temp;
                }
        }
    }
    return sum%mod;
}
```

1. I am trying to achieve results for `N>=1 to N<=200000`.
2. Can it be that the variable sum is going beyond the scope of `long long int` after a certain limit?

Comment: How are you calling this? A loop in a loop is not going to perform that well for large values of *N*.

Comment: Note: The *compiler* has nothing to do with taking a long time. This is 100% your code.

Comment: What is this code even doing? The `i&j` stuff seems especially bizarre. Are you finding numbers with no overlapping bits, and then...adding up the multiples? The use of `temp` here is completely pointless. You can just do `sum += i * j`.

Comment: You wrote O(n^2) code.  Quadratic complexity hurts, do it 50,000 times and 2.5 million is no longer flash, bang, done on the fastest hardware.

Comment: You've a complexity O(n^2). Nothing is going to improve speed unless unless you're getting rid of the inner loop

Comment: If `N <= 200000` then overflow of `sum` should not be a problem.  Think about the math: what's the largest that `i*j` could be on any given iteration?  How many such terms are added?  Multiply these and note that the result is less than the maximum `long long int`.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your answer. This question was asked in a hackathon where the condition was that if i (bitwise AND) j is 0 then you have to get the product of i and j and keep adding the similar ones (in this case , sum=sum+(i*j) ). I was able to get the sample test case right but failed in the hidden test cases with Error: " Time Limit Exceeded."

Comment: I would explore if there's an algorithmic way here to skip over all the obvious non-matches. There's probably a way to avoid a whole ton of comparisons that are going to be duds.

Answer (score 2):

```
temp=i*j;
```

Since `i,j` are both of type `int`, this multiplication is done as `int` (likely signed 32-bit), and if it overflows the largest `int` (2**31-1) then you have undefined behavior and will certainly not get the right answer.  A little quick math shows this will happen as soon as `N` exceeds `46340` which is around the `50000` you mention.  The fact that the result is assigned to a variable of type `long long int` doesn't change the way the sub-expression `i*j` is evaluated, so it doesn't solve your overflow problem.

To get the multiplication to be done as `long long int` (at least 64 bits), you have to cast one or both of the operands:

```
temp = ((long long int)i) * j;
```

(Cast has higher precedence than multiplication so you can actually write `temp = (long long int)i * j;` but I tend to find this is less clear to read.)

This would explain the "possibly wrong answer" but has nothing to do with the slowness, which as others mentioned comes inherently from your quadratic algorithm.  However even with `N=200000` it finishes in about 8 seconds on my computer.  Make sure you are using a good-quality optimizing compiler and that you have optimizations turned on.

Your question (2) about overflowing `sum` is not an issue though.  Each of the summands `i*j` is at most `N**2`, and there are at most `N` such summands, so the maximum value of `sum` is at most `N**3`.  You can verify that `200000**3` is still much smaller than `2**63`.

Comment: Or `int64_t` instead of the longlonglonglong stuff.